# HTML responsive Slideshow

Tags: html, css, optimization, slider, responsive

I have a website with a full width Slideshow in the header.
The images in the slideshow cannot be cropped.
Right now i set that my slideshow allows has width: 100% and a variable height.

The problem is that on phones (due to the different screen proportions) the slider looks super slim.

As I already said: I cannot crop the images. so i probably have to create a new slider for mobile devices.
What is the best way to do this?

If i just do something like:

```
<div class="mobileslider">
```

for mobile devices and

```
<div class="slider">
```

for desktops, I could hide one element via css.
However, both sliders would load, wont they?
Whats the most efficient way to do this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to hide the element and display the other one with a couple of media queries based on screen size.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .slider {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .mobileslider {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but this causes performance issues, doesnt it?
I mean, the html and all the images would be loaded, they would just not be displayed...

Comment: No, there is no performance hit because your CSS is telling the HTML engine to simply ignore that element and all its children. The elements don't go in the render tree.